# Get SOAP request and Response from the wsdl file from a client

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis, axis

I am using Apche Axis2 for a web service client. I know to get the output of a web service. But I want to get the soap Request and response from the wsdl file.

My wsdl is `http://localhost:8080/getDetails?wsdl`

It would be great if some can share their experiences.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a software for that, use SoapUI.

If you want to do it from Java, you have these options.

1. Generate the classes for a SOAP Client using `wsdl2java` command.
   There are many ways of doing this depends on the implementation you used.
2. Generate the classes for a SOAP Client using maven plugin, use this [axistools-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/axistools-maven-plugin/)

After this search for a class having a name "...Locator" and "..PortType", use these classes.

OR,

Search for an Interface which has all the exposed methods and find a way to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have the generated the classes from Apache Axis 2.  I cannot find these classes in it. But my program is successfully executing. Can you help how to proceed further.

Comment: There must be an interface class which has all the methods exposed by the Web Service. If not, your classes are not generated completly.

Comment: What commands did you used? How did you generated the Stub classes?

Comment: Apache Axis 2 generates all of them automatically.

Comment: Search for an Interface which has all the exposed methods and find a way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SoapUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui/4.0/) Tool , provide your WSDL path to this tool , it will load all operations from WSDL once if you click on perticular operation you can get sample SOAP request(XML payloads).